# External monitors have no signal after boot if laptop lid is closed

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, lightdm, external-monitor, docking

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad t440s with the intel graphics card running Ubuntu Desktop Trusty 14.04.4 LTS. This issue occurs with the ThinkPad Ultra Dock with two external monitors attached to it.

After booting up, I can see the login screen for a second before both external screens go blank (no signal). If a switch to console login with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>F1</kbd> , the external monitors fire up. Now this only happens if the laptop lid is closed, so I have to keep it open all the time, in which case the two external monitors work just fine.

Also, I am noticing quite a bit of delay while logging on with the external monitors (about 15 seconds), which is not there if the laptop is not attached to the docking station.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Below is the x-0-greeter.log

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:496: Starting unity-greeter 14.04.11 UID=112 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:499: Setting cursor
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:513: Loading command line options
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:541: Setting GTK+ settings
[+0.05s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:564: Creating Unity Greeter
[+0.05s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:57: Creating background surface
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Connecting to display manager...
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Wrote 18 bytes to daemon
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Read 150 bytes from daemon
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Connected version=1.10.6 default-session=ubuntu show-manual-login=false hide-users=false has-guest-account=true show-remote-login=true
[+0.07s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:336: LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=(null)
[+0.07s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:368: LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=(null)
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: user-list.vala:1030: Adding/updating user angel (Angel Kafazov)
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Loading sessions from org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.08s] DEBUG: user-list.vala:1012: Adding guest account entry
[+0.09s] DEBUG: Loaded session /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop (Ubuntu, This session logs you into Ubuntu)
[+0.09s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for user angel...
[+0.09s] DEBUG: Wrote 21 bytes to daemon
[+0.09s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:185: Screen is 1920x1080 pixels
[+0.09s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 0 is 1920x1080 pixels at 0,0
[+0.09s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 1 is 1920x1080 pixels at 0,0
[+0.09s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 2 is 1920x1080 pixels at 0,0
[+0.09s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:567: Showing greeter
[+0.09s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:252: Showing main window
[+0.10s] DEBUG: background.vala:483: Regenerating backgrounds
[+0.10s] DEBUG: background.vala:68: Making background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png at 1920x1080
[+0.10s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:610: Starting main loop
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Read 35 bytes from daemon
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+0.11s] DEBUG: background.vala:68: Making background /usr/share/backgrounds/Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg at 1920x1080
[+0.14s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:75: Acquired org.gnome.SessionManager
[+0.14s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:102: Acquired org.gnome.ScreenSaver
[+0.14s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:159: All bus names acquired, starting unity-settings-daemon
[+0.19s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:235: starting system-ready sound
[+0.22s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:538: Adding indicator object 0x13689d0 at position 0
[+0.23s] DEBUG: Connected to Application Indicator Service.
[+0.26s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:538: Adding indicator object 0x1368710 at position 0
[+0.28s] DEBUG: Request current apps
[+0.31s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:538: Adding indicator object 0x1368f50 at position 2
[+0.38s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:185: Screen is 1920x1080 pixels
[+0.38s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 0 is 1920x1080 pixels at 0,0
[+0.38s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 1 is 1920x1080 pixels at 0,0
[+0.38s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 2 is 1920x1080 pixels at 0,0
[+0.39s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /usr/share/backgrounds/Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg complete
[+0.42s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:538: Adding indicator object 0x1368450 at position 3
[+0.42s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png complete
[+0.49s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:185: Screen is 5760x1080 pixels
[+0.49s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 0 is 1920x1080 pixels at 0,0
[+0.49s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 1 is 1920x1080 pixels at 1920,0
[+0.49s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 2 is 1920x1080 pixels at 3840,0
[+0.63s] DEBUG: background.vala:483: Regenerating backgrounds
[+0.63s] DEBUG: background.vala:68: Making background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png at 1920x1080
[+0.63s] DEBUG: background.vala:68: Making background /usr/share/backgrounds/Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg at 1920x1080
[+0.73s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:538: Adding indicator object 0x1368c90 at position 3

** (nm-applet:3495): CRITICAL **: nm_secret_agent_register: assertion 'priv->registered == FALSE' failed
[+0.81s] DEBUG: Building new application entry: :1.20  with icon: nm-device-wired at position 0
[+0.81s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:538: Adding indicator object 0x17ce4e0 at position 5

** (unity-settings-daemon:3517): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'RegisterClient'
[+1.02s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /usr/share/backgrounds/Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg complete
[+1.03s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png complete
[+5.16s] DEBUG: Providing response to display manager
[+5.16s] DEBUG: Wrote 25 bytes to daemon
[+5.17s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+5.17s] DEBUG: Read 17 bytes from daemon
[+5.17s] DEBUG: Authentication complete for user angel with return code 0
[+5.17s] DEBUG: Starting session ubuntu
[+5.17s] DEBUG: Wrote 18 bytes to daemon
[+5.17s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+5.17s] DEBUG: Read 4 bytes from daemon
[+5.17s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:605: Got a SIGTERM
[+5.17s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:613: Cleaning up
[+5.17s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:621: Upstart exited with return value 0
[+5.17s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:633: AT-SPI exited with return value 0
[+5.17s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:639: Exiting
init: indicator-power main process (3510) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (3504) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-messages main process (3498) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-datetime main process (3512) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-session main process (3519) killed by TERM signal
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
nm-applet-Message: PID 3495 (we are 3495) sent signal 15, shutting down...
init: indicator-application main process (3537) killed by TERM signal

** (unity-settings-daemon:3517): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down

(nm-applet:3495): libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to send signal for NewStatus: The connection is closed

(unity-settings-daemon:3517): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.

(nm-applet:3495): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 132 was not found when attempting to remove it
```